# Поэлементное сравнение двух массивов python

Tags: python, numpy

Есть два массива. Например, a=[1,2,3,4,5,6] и b=[3,1,3,4,1,6]. С помощью numpy нужно реализовать вывод общих элементов с поэлементным сравнением, т.е. [3,4,6]. Есть ли специальные функции в numpy?
Я вижу только такое решение:

```
for i in range (0,len(b)):
    if b[[i]]==a[[i]]:
        array.append(int(b[[i]]))
```

Вопрос 2. (не касается того, что выше) - что называется вектором строкой? Если дан массив a=array[1,2,3,4,5], если от него взять print(a) - вывод будет считаться вектором строкой?

Comment: `[[1, 2, 3]]` - вектор-строка (`shape = (1, 3)`). `[[1], [2], [3]]` - вектор-столбец (`shape=(3, 1)`).

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте два вопроса в одном. В конце концов, вопрос будет закрыт.

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать логическую индексацию:

```
a[a==b]
```

Answer (score 0):

если делать только через numpy -
первый вариант с помощью np.intersect1d:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = np.array([3,1,3,4,1,6])
print(np.intersect1d(a, b))
```

второй вариант с помощью np.in1d:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = np.array([3,1,3,4,1,6])
c = a[np.in1d(a, b)]
print(c)
```

если просто пересечение списков, то:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [3,1,3,4,1,6]
print(list(set(a) & set(b)))
```

Comment: ваш ответ отвечает на другой вопрос - автор вопроса хочет сравнивать элементы с одинаковыми индексами